# socket encryp and decryption between dart and c++

Tags: c++, c++11, dart

I work on Chat server in c++, data tranfser between client(dart) and server(c++), i want to use AES encryption for data and i have many question

1_ Which one should I choose? AES-GCM or AES-CTR, If you prefer another method of doing this, please explain.

2_ I know of several library and class for this, such as [AesCryptoServiceProvider Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) , [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/)  which one do you think I should use, or if you know another library or documation , name it

3_ In my previous experience, i changed data like message and message information to string, encrypted string , add the first and last encrypted string with a special character so that I can get the healthy data and finaly i decrypted in server or client and it worked well, my question here is this the standard method? because i have heard elsewhere that each byte must be encrypted separately and sent with a socket, not collectively.

4_I did not find a good library for aes inside the dart, and my question is that I can write the class for decrypt and encrypt data in c++ and use in dart ?

thanks

Comment: Why not use OpenSSL (or similar) to create full end-to-end encryption using TLS?

Comment: @rveerd I want to use maximum speed to transfer data ,and at best, 60 MBps TLS handshake is slow than manually aes encrypt and need 6 request for accept handshake

Comment: The TLS handshake only happens when client and server connect. Keep the connection open as long as the client is online.

Comment: @rveerd I know, I said for the start connection, tls is really good, but I need to make a very fast custom آhandshake